# Emoji One integration into Redactor editor

Tags: javascript, html, emoji, redactor, redactor.js

I tried [this](http://git.emojione.com/demos/1.5.0/autocomplete.html) and it works great on regular textarea.
Now I want to use that in Redactor editor. But Redactor uses textarea just to send data when form is submitted so example code from link above doesn't work.

Do I have to write plugin for redactor or there is quick hack?

Thanks.